# Getting secondry can bus data via PRIMARY can bus

Tags: can-bus

I want to get the data of the middle or lower  can bus that is connected to BCM
(body control management) via the high baud can bus -that is connected to the Obd port.

Does someone has did it?
What kind of request I need to ask?

Comment: You will find several questions on here about communicating with the can bus, have a search.

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to give more info about the vehicle in question? Make, Model, Year, Engine etc etc